# Probability of needing more than 7 coin tosses to get heads for at least 2 days in a year

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Suppose everyday someone flips a coin until they get heads and records
> the amount of coin flips needed. **Approximate** the probability that
> in a year of 365 days there are at least 2 days when it takes strictly
> more than 7 coin flips to get heads.

My approach to this question was to first use the geometric distribution $Geom(0.5) = (1-0.5)^{k-1}0.5$ and then do $1-\Sigma_{k=1}^70.5^{k-1}0.5$ to get the probability of needing more than 7 tosses on a given day. Call this probability $p$. Then we have a binomial distribution $Binom(365,p)$ with $np^2 \leq 0.05$, so we should be able to approximate it with $Poisson(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ equal to the expectation value of $Binom(365,p)$, and then taking 1 minus the result we get from $Poisson(\lambda)$ with $k=2$ gives the final answer.

However this is apparently incorrect. If someone could advise me on what the correct approach to this question is or what was wrong with my approach I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual numerical result that you obtained, I don't know where your error is, but what I can say is that your approach is reasonable.

There is one error, however.  If $N$ is the random number of days for which more than $7$ flips are needed, and you approximate $N$ as a Poisson distribution, then the desired probability that there are at least $2$ days in the year for which more than $7$ flips are needed is given by the expression
$$1 - \Pr[N \color{red}{\le 1}],$$
and not $1 - \Pr[N = 2]$ as you seem to be saying.